# Cannot complete Provision step in Visual Studio Teams Toolkit

Tags: visual-studio, teams-toolkit

In VS 2022, v17.9.3, I installed the latest Teams Toolkit extension and created a project from the Microsoft Teams App template.

*The issue is that the Teams Toolkit's "Provision in the Cloud..." wizard doesn't let me past the initial screen.*

Here is what I do:

I go to Provision in the cloud

[image]

On the next screen I click the "Re-enter your credentials" link, which, after authentication, results in "Loading subscriptions...":

[image]

Then for a brief second, I see 3 textboxes, which what appears to be the selections needed for the provision step, but then the textboxes disappear and I am back to the screen that asks me to re-enter my credentials.

[image]

- I tried logging out of all accounts, which forces to authenticate from scratch.
- I tried setting default browser to Chrome or Edge.
- I tried the equivalent action in Visual Studio Code Teams Toolkit, and had no problems with the provision step in Visual Studio Code. But, we really need to stay with Visual Studio and .NET Template since that's the environment we currently use for other projects.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reporting the issue. According to your description, it seems Teams Toolkit meets an exception when getting your account's subscriptions. Can you try to delete the cache folder `%USERPROFILE%\.fx\account`, restart your Visual Studio and try provision again.

For this time, you can pay attention to the `Teams Toolkit` output window to see if there are some error messages.

Also, I hope to know if your project has been provisioned before? You can check the `AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID` under `env\.env.dev`. If provisioned before, this value is not empty.

Comment: Tried deleting .fx/account, and can confirm that .env.dev doesn't have any settings except for TEAMSFX_ENV and APP_NAME_SUFFIX. No output in Teams Tooltip Output Window. And will the screen flashes with 3 texboxes and then I am redirected to "Re-enter credentials". Is there any way to trace this further?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Unfortunately, if cleaning cache cannot work around, switching to another account may help you for now. Sorry about that. We will investigate how to fix/improve it.

By the way, I have seen your last update that you caught the error by Fiddler. Can you tell us why deleting it? That may help us locate the root cause. Thank you!